# Performace Analysis for Android App.

Tags: android, performance

I'm a Computer Science student and I'm working on an Android app. for my final year project.
This is a rule in my college to perform some sort of performance analysis in every project that we do.

And this is the point where I got stuck.

Can anyone tell me what sort of performance-analysis I can do in my Project?

[Please do explain on how that should be performed.]

Comment: While i'm not sure I agree with the downvote (not by me), I think you should be more specific with what your application does. There are many ways to test performance, but it is highly specific to what you are doing. You can test UI performance, performance of calculations you are running etc.. For a school project though, unless you are building your own UI elements or animations and things like that then I don't think performance analysis of UI is very important.. More likely you would want to analyze the performance of the algorithms/computations you are performing.

Comment: @MattWolfe~~ I got your point. thanks for that. 
Is there any way that I can measure the Performance by running my app on various devices and finally showing some statistics on which hardware was best-suited for optimal performance?

Comment: You really need to give us more to go on. This is objectively answerable, but not without more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your project in Eclipse, you can open the DDMS perspective. There, you will be able to profile the app, and get a feel for how long each method is taking / what takes the longest.

It's pretty easy. Once in the DDMS perspective, make sure the app is running, click the device it is running on, and then find the icon above the devices for 'start profiling'. When you are done, click the stop profiling icon, and eclipse will present you with some nifty graphs that you can zoom into.

Answer (score 0):

This is far too broad of a question for SO (and in my opinion to be given out as an assignment) If that is seriously all the direction you were given "preformance analysis" then I would go ask your professor to elaborate some more.

in the mean time here are a few links that may be relavent:

http://www.flurry.com/

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/android.html

If your app is to be published on the market, the Developer console provides quite a few different statistics related to installs over time and versions and such.

see here for more info: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/02/new-app-stats-for-publishers-on-android.html

Comment: Is there any way that I can measure the Performance by running my app on various devices and finally showing some statistics on which hardware was best-suited for optimal performance?

Comment: Sure, add Log statments that will output how long each section of code takes in millis. You could then observe the differences in how long different processes take on different devices.